# using regexp to test for no special character or only numbers after `@` symbol in email address

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I test an email address to retrieve the following results:

```
mohamed_12@yahoo.com => valid
9mohamed_12@yahoo.co => valid
_mohamed_12@a123_a4.co => valid
9mohamed_12@112344.co => invalid after @ only number
9mohamed_12@_112344.co => invalid after @ special character.
```

The regex I tried to use is: `/[a-zA-Z0-9_].+(@[a-z0-9].+\.+[a-z]{2,3})/g`

Comment: How come the third turn out to be valid ? it has `_` after `@`, or why the last one is invalid

Comment: Number-only domain names are perfectly valid.

Comment: what is the significance of this ? If you are looking for a real email then, number only domains are valid

Comment: Here is a site to help with regex visualisation. https://regexper.com/#%2F%5Ba-zA-Z0-9_%5D.%2B%28%40%5Ba-z0-9%5D.%2B%5C.%2B%5Ba-z%5D%7B2%2C3%7D%29%2Fg

Answer (score 0):

You can use "negative lookahead":

Try this

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_].+((?!@_)(?!@[\d]+\.)(@[a-z0-9_]+)\.[a-z]{2,3})
```

It makes sure followings are met for **domain**:

- It is not a number only
- No special characters in it (only `_`)
- Cannot start with `_`
- Numbers *with* characters are allowed for domain

Comment: How to allow only _  after  '@' word, now it allows `$%` all

Answer (score 0):

You could match at least 1 time a-z or an underscore and use a negative lookahead `(?!` to make sure that there is no underscore right after the `@`

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@(?!_)[a-z0-9_]*[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*\.[a-z]{2,3}$
```

**Pattern parts**

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` Match 1+ times what is listed in the character class (Or use `\w+` instead)
- `@(?!_)` Match @, assert what is directly on the right is not `_`
- `[a-z0-9_]*[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*` Match at least a single char a-z or `_`
- `\.[a-z]{2,3}` Match a dot and match 2 - 3 times a char a-z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3fTd3O/1)

```js
let pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@(?!_)[a-z0-9_]*[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*\.[a-z]{2,3}$/;
[
  "mohamed_12@yahoo.com",
  "9mohamed_12@yahoo.co",
  "_mohamed_12@a123_a4.co",
  "9mohamed_12@112344.co",
  "9mohamed_12@_112344.co"
].forEach(s => console.log(s + " --> " + pattern.test(s)))
```